# Variable not holding reference to `this`

Tags: javascript

```js
function test1() {
  this.name = 'test1';
  var that = this;

  function test2() {
    this.name = 'test2';
    console.log(that.name);
  }

  test2();
}

test1();
```

When this executes, I expect the console to log out `test1`. Why do I get `test2` instead? I expect the `that` variable to hold a reference to the `test1` function.

Comment: Because `that` and both `this`es point to the global object `window`. You're not creating an instance (using `new`) so that the `this` (of `test1`) will be that instance, you are just calling the functions directly.

Comment: Try: `var a = new test1();` Or just `new test1();` (for short).

Comment: It would help you undersant if you logged those vriables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: *"that variable to hold a reference to the test1 function."* That isn't what "this" or "that" are in JavaScript. They don't hold references to functions, they hold object references.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable **that** becomes an object reference since you assign keyword **this** to it. That means the variable **that** will be an object and it will have a reference to **this**(that is, the current object).

Further, the variable **that** is not a **value type**. It is an object.

For more on this, search on " value type vs reference types ".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In a function definition, this refers to the "owner" of the function.
Please find the description in inline comments.
Rearranging your code according to the order of execution,

```
test1();                      //Now this is called by window object
function test1() {
  this.name = 'test1';        //window.name = 'test1';
  var that = this;            //that is also now window obj
  test2();                    //this.test2 or window.test2()
  function test2() {
    this.name = 'test2';      //window.name is now test 2
    console.log(that.name);   //since in third step, that is window, that.name or window.name is now test 2
  }
}
```